ASP.NET MVC web app on .NET 4.7.1 - migrated NuGet TinyMCE 4.5.4 to 7.3.0 - findreplace feature missing after migration
I have an ASP.NET MVC web app that uses tinyMCE Rich Text Editor 4.5.4 NuGet package.
Since it is vulnerable, I've updated to the latest version 7.3.0:
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea.dataEditor',
    content_style: ".mce-content-body {font-size:9pt;font-family:Segoe UI;}",
    height: 300,
    theme: 'modern',
    menubar: 'edit',
    force_br_newlines: false,
    force_p_newlines: false,
    forced_root_block: '',
    invalid_styles: {
        '*': 'margin'
    },
    plugins: [
  'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
  'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen',
  'insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality',
  'emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools codesample toc'
    ],
    fullpage_default_font_family: "Segoe UI;",
    fullpage_default_font_size: "9pt",
    contextmenu: "paste",
    paste_create_paragraphs: false,
    paste_create_linebreaks: false,
    paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste: true,
    paste_convert_middot_lists: false,
    paste_unindented_list_class: "unIndentedList",
    paste_convert_headers_to_strong: true,
    paste_retain_style_properties: "margin, padding, width, height, font-weight, color, text-align, text-decoration, border, background, float, display",
    paste_remove_styles_if_webkit: false,
    paste_preprocess: function (pl, o) {
        o.content = o.content.replace(/”/g, "\"");
        o.content = o.content.replace(/“/g, "\"");
        o.content = o.content.replace(/’/g, "\'");
    },
    toolbar: 'undo redo | fontselect fontsizeselect | numlist bullist checklist | outdent indent | preview',
    font_formats: 'Segoe UI=segoe ui',//;Andale Mono=andale mono,times;Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif;Arial Black=arial black,avant garde;Book Antiqua=book antiqua,palatino;Comic Sans MS=comic sans ms,sans-serif;Courier New=courier new,courier;Georgia=georgia,palatino;Helvetica=helvetica;Impact=impact,chicago;Symbol=symbol;Tahoma=tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;Terminal=terminal,monaco;Times New Roman=times new roman,times;Trebuchet MS=trebuchet ms,geneva;Verdana=verdana,geneva;Webdings=webdings;Wingdings=wingdings,zapf dingbats',
    fontsize_formats: "9pt",//"8pt 9pt 10pt 10.5pt 11pt 12pt 14pt 18pt 24pt 36pt",
    image_advtab: true,
    init_instance_callback: function myCustomInitInstance(inst) {
        var editor = $(inst.getContainer())[0];
        var readonly = $(editor).parents(".Details").find("input[name*='IsCompleted']").val() == "True";
        if (readonly) {
            inst.setMode('readonly');
        }
    },
    setup: function (ed) {
        ed.on('init', function (ed) {
            this.getDoc().body.style.fontSize = "9pt";
            ed.target.editorCommands.execCommand("fontName", false, "Segoe UI");
            //ed.target.editorCommands.execCommand("fontSize", false, "17.5");
        });
    }
});

This was not working in 7.3.0 and it worked after adding this in the above and commented theme.
skin: 'oxide',  // This sets the skin to 'oxide', which is the modern equivalent
menubar: {
    edit: true, // Show the 'Edit' menu
    file: false, // Hide other menus
    view: false,
    insert: false,
    format: false,
    tools: false
},


 toolbar: 'findreplace | undo redo | formatselect | bold italic forecolor backcolor | emoticons codesample template | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat',

The "findreplace" feature is missing after migration to latest tinyMCE rich textbox.
Please advise.
